# midifile: getDurationInSeconds is 0 for all events

Tags: c++, midi

I downloaded the midifile library from sapp.org today.
I created a testfile in guitar pro 5, exported it as midi and opened it with c++.
So far, so good. I can read all the tracks and the BPM are correct.
I now want to go from event to event and read the key and the event duration. While I get the according key information, the duration returns zero.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "../midi/include/Options.h"
#include "../midi/include/MidiFile.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if( argc != 4 ){
        std::cout << "Error: Invalid argument count. Use: ./drumgen srcmid outwav map" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    MidiFile drumInput;
    bool readFile = drumInput.read(argv[1]);
    if( !readFile ){
        std::cout << "Error: File " << argv[1] << " not found." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int tracks = drumInput.getTrackCount();
    std::cout << "Tracks: " << tracks << std::endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < tracks; i++ ){
        int eventCount = drumInput.getEventCount(i);
        for( int j = 0; j < eventCount; j++ ){
            MidiEvent ev = drumInput.getEvent(i, j);
            int key = ev.getKeyNumber();
            int dur = ev.getDurationInSeconds();
            std::cout << key << " " << dur << ";";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Eventcount: " << eventCount << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My example MIDI file is here:
http://wikisend.com/download/186754/drumtest.mid
The library can be found here:
http://midifile.sapp.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a MIDI file, events do not have durations; notes consist of two events, note on and note off.

To find out the length of a note, you have to search for the corresponding event pairs.

Apparently, Midifile does not do this automatically for some reason, but requires you do call `MidiFile::linkNotePairs()`.